# Keep playing a sound over and over again in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, playback, audio, repeat

I'm trying to create a MATLAB program to play a sound over and over again every couple of minutes. Right now I have it set to play every couple of seconds, just to get some bugs out of the system. However, when my program tries to replay the sound I get this error:

```
 ??? Error using ==>
 audioplayer.audioplayer>audioplayer.resume at 710
 A given audio device may only be opened once.

 Error in ==> audioplayer.play at 88
     obj.resume();

 Error in ==>
      audiorecorder.audiorecorder>audiorecorder.play at
      779
      play(player, varargin{:})

 Error in ==> Voice at 17
     play(voice);
```

My code so far is this:

```
 clc;
 clear all;
 clear main;

 %File to play my voice to tell me to keep studying


     voice = audiorecorder;
     disp('Start speaking.');
     recordblocking(voice, 3);
     disp('DONE');


while i ~= 100;
 pause(1);
 play(voice);
 i = 0;
end
```

Basically my question is is there a way to keep writing my same sound file to a different name, and then continuously play the new file? I thought about making a matrix, and then just use a "for" loop to traverse it then play the new file, but I don't know how to make a matrix out of sound files. Is there a different command I can use instead of "play" that will let me keep playing it?

**EDIT:** Doing more research on this now, since I've never actually learned about this in class, but would it be best to just create a new file containing my sound and then repeadetly access the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the code you posted, I think the issue is that you only `pause(1)` which I suspect is shorter than the sound so you try and `play(voice)` while it is still playing from the previous loop. Instead of `play` use **[playblocking](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioplayer.playblocking.html)** as this should stop the loop until the sound is finished.

Answer (score 0):

this error "A given audio device may only be opened once" it mean...
when you run your code, if another program or function call "audioplayer".
The system will have a problem, so you need to include some code for check "Running" property of "audioplayer" before playing loop. 
such as
.....
.....
A=get(hplay,'Running');
if(strcmp(A,'off')
......player your code....
end