# Mac Matlab/ Simulinks Real time audio input

Tags: macos, matlab, audio, real-time, simulink

I am building a simple real time delay system on my mac (2010-11 model; os x Mavericks; serial audio input) using Simulinks (Matlab 2014a) consisting of a 'Audio Input' block, an 'Audio Output' block a 'delay' block and an adder (to add the delayed signal to the original signal), but I receive the error: 'Error in 'untitled/From Audio Device': A given audio device may only be opened once.' twice for the audio input block.

When I try the same using a audio file as my input I get the desired results. Also the same diagram works fine on a windows machine.

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are trying to output a sound to the audio device, while at the same time to trying to read from the audio device. That won't work, you can't do that. See [Keep playing a sound over and over again in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226309/keep-playing-a-sound-over-and-over-again-in-matlab) for a similar issue in MATLAB. You need to somehow wait for the reading part to complete before outputting the sound back to the audio device, or use two different devices, one for reading and one for writing.

I suspect the same model worked on a Windows machine because it probably had two audio devices (maybe a built-in and an external), and the model automatically detected this, reading from one device, and outputting to the other. The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/dsp/ref/fromaudiodevice.html) for both blocks says:

> Use the Device parameter to specify the device from which to acquire
>   audio. This parameter is automatically populated based on the audio
>   devices installed on your system.

which again, reinforces that theory. If you still have access to the Windows machine, you can double-check that this is the case.